# SQL query causing duplicates

Tags: mysql, sql

To make this simple, I have only listed the relevant fields below:

```
Table 1 (question_data_table):
 - UserID
 - QuestionID
 - Strength
 - Timestamp


Table 2 (user_question_waitlist):
 - UserID
 - QuestionID
 - Timestamp
```

I am running the following query:

```
INSERT INTO user_question_waitlist (UserID, QuestionID, Timestamp) 
SELECT UserID, QuestionID, Timestamp FROM question_data_table 
WHERE Strength <= 0 AND question_data_table.QuestionID NOT IN 
(SELECT QuestionID FROM user_question_waitlist 
WHERE question_data_table.UserID = user_question_waitlist.UserID)
```

The issue is, where 5 rows should be inserted into user_question_waitlist. It inserts 31.

[image]

Sample data from question_data_table:

[image: Sample Data:]

user_question_waitlist data varies a lot, it can be empty for example or contain data for other users.

As an example, using the sample data above if I have the following data in the user_question_waitlist:
[image]

...and then run the query, it inserts 6 rows to produce this:
[image]

Comment: You would need to provide sample data (perhaps through a SQL Fiddle).  Your code is correct.  You are misunderstanding something.

Comment: I believe Gordon is right. I suspect you have duplicated/incorrect data inside your question_data_table

Comment: Question: Is your user_question_waitlist table EMPTY before you run your query?

Comment: If you comment a line with `INSERT ....` in the query, then how many rows does the query return ?

Comment: @Gerardo Yes, it can be empty (see the sample data)

Comment: @kordirko It returns an empty data set, unless I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: It seems to me I'm not linking the tables properly, but I'm not sure how to.

Comment: Could you delete all rows from `user_question_waitlist ` and then run the `SELECT` query again ? But only `SELECT` alone, with commented a line with `INSERT ...`

Comment: "This should be impossible", essentially, if you're using the exact query you posted.  My immediate thought is... how are you executing the command?  Might you be kicking off multiple versions of the command somehow?  If the display is from a web interface, are you hitting refresh (which may re-run the command)?  What is the transaction level you're using?  I suspect multiple calls are being submitted concurrently somehow.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse I'm running it through phpmyadmin, and when it runs it's saying 31 new rows inserted so I don't think this is the case.

Comment: @kordirko it returned the following: https://gyazo.com/f9d734a4c6026587b0ca54b09e577747

Comment: Well, the SELECT alone returned 25 rows. Not 5, nor 31 rows, but 25 rows. The issue is in the SELECT query, not the INSERT. You need to change the SELECT query somehow.

Comment: @kordirko is there a way to say question_data_table.UserID & question_data_table.QuestionID not in the same row in user_question_waitlist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding DISTINCT to the end of your select.

Comment: That's solved it, but that's dealing with the result instead of actually solving the problem is it not?

Comment: From your sample data I believe it's actually solving your problem.